# CSS float leaves gap

Tags: html, css

Given the below simple html, how to stack the green DIVs on top of each other without the space (using or not using floats)? I don't know why there is space between the third and forth green DIVs.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}
.left {
  width: 20%;
  background-color: #00CC66;
  height: 50px;
  float: left;
  clear: left;
}
.right {
  width: 20%;
  background-color: #0033FF;
  height: 99px;
  float: right;
  clear: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="left"></div>
<div class="right"></div>
<div class="left"></div>
<div class="right"></div>
<div class="left"></div>
<div class="right"></div>
<div class="left"></div>
<div class="right"></div>
```

Comment: Who clarity,  #00CC66 (i.e. `<div class = "left"/>`) is green and #0033FF (i.e. `<div class = "right"/>`) is blue

Answer (score 2):

A [floated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float) div can't be above (in terms of vertical position) a preceding floated element, even if it's floated to the other side. Therefore the 4th green div can't be above the 3rd blue div and is pushed downwards.

Answer (score 0):

Clear div should be in between 'left' & 'right' not on every div.

**Solution 1**

```
<div class="left"></div>
<div class="right"></div>
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
<div class="left"></div>
<div class="right"></div>
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
<div class="left"></div>
<div class="right"></div>
```

css

```
* {
  margin: 0;
}
.left {
  display: block;
  width: 20%;
  background-color: #00CC66;
  height: 50px;
  float: left;
}
.right {
  width: 20%;
  background-color: #0033FF;
  height: 50px;
  float: right;
}
```

A little clearner

**Solution 2**

```
<div class="left"></div>
<div class="right"></div>
<div class="clr left"></div>
<div class="right"></div>
<div class="clr left"></div>
<div class="right"></div>
<div class="clr left"></div>
<div class="right"></div>
```

css:

```
* {
  margin: 0;
}
.left {
  display: block;
  width: 20%;
  background-color: #00CC66;
  height: 50px;
  float: left;
}
.right {
  width: 20%;
  background-color: #0033FF;
  height: 50px;
  float: right;
}

.clr{
  clear: both;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

change this in style tag :
.left { width: 20%; background-color: #00CC66; height: 70px; float: left; clear:left;}